# Sqlite save notes and make listview android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I am new to Java and android environment, i want to make a simple notes project that, user will write title and body and click to save button in a NotesDetail page then, i will display as a listview in the home page. So far, i have done the layouts and listview and i want to keep the information with the sqlite. I am stuck in this phase. I can manually add in a listview (say add ,but not the user input),but user input not saving and not showing. I will post my code below. I hope someone help me. Mainly i am doing to job in Notes activity, and i am showing in the MainActivity.

NotesDB.java

```
public class NotesDbAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="notes.db"; //database name
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION= 1; //database version
    //public static final String TABLE_NAME="notes2";




   public NotesDbAdapter(Context context) {

       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }



    //Creating Tables

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(NoteContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + NoteContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME);
        //Create tables again
        onCreate(db);

    }
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
 }
```

Note.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Note {

    private String nTitle;
    private String nBody;
    private String Iuri;
    private String nLocation;
    private int Nid;

    public int getNid() {
        return Nid;
    }

    public void setNid(int nid) {
        Nid = nid;
    }

    public static List<Note> not;

    public Note(String nTitle) {
        this.nTitle = nTitle;
    }

    public Note(String nTitle, String nBody) {
        this.nTitle = nTitle;
        this.nBody = nBody;
    }


    public Note(String nTitle, String nBody, String iuri) {
        this.nTitle = nTitle;
        this.nBody = nBody;
        Iuri = iuri;
    }

    public Note(String nTitle, String nBody, String iuri, String nLocation) {
        this.nTitle = nTitle;
        this.nBody = nBody;
        Iuri = iuri;
        this.nLocation = nLocation;
    }

    public String getnBody() {
        return nBody;
    }

    public void setnBody(String nBody) {
        this.nBody = nBody;
    }

    public String getnTitle() {
        return nTitle;
    }

    public void setnTitle(String nTitle) {
        this.nTitle = nTitle;
    }

    public String getIuri() {
        return Iuri;
    }

    public void setIuri(String iuri) {
        Iuri = iuri;
    }

    public String getnLocation() {
        return nLocation;
    }

    public void setnLocation(String nLocation) {
        this.nLocation = nLocation;
    }

    public static List<Note> getNotes(){
        if(not==null) {
            not = new ArrayList<>();
            not.add(new Note("Deneme title","Deneme body"));
            not.add(new Note("Deneme title2","Deneme body2"));
            not.add(new Note("Deneme title3","Deneme body3"));
            not.add(new Note("Deneme title2","Deneme body2"));
            not.add(new Note("Deneme title2","Deneme body2"));
            not.add(new Note("Deneme title2","Deneme body2"));
            not.add(new Note("Deneme title2","Deneme body2"));
            not.add(new Note("Deneme title2","Deneme body2"));
            not.add(new Note("Deneme title2","Deneme body2"));
            not.add(new Note("Deneme title2","Deneme body2"));
            not.add(new Note("Deneme title2","Deneme body2"));
            not.add(new Note("Deneme title2","Deneme body2"));
        }

        return not;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return nTitle + " " + nBody;
    }

}
```

NoteDetail.java

```
public class NoteDetail extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    NotesDbAdapter helpers = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    ArrayList<Note> notes;
    NoteContract.FeedEntry help;
    EditText eTitle;
    EditText eBody;
    Button savebuttons;
    String URI = "a";
    String Location = "b";
    public int id = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.note_detail);

        eTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
        eBody = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNote);
        savebuttons = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
        savebuttons.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        insertData(eTitle.getText().toString(), eBody.getText().toString(), URI, Location);

        //TextView txtOutput;
        //txtOutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtData);
    }


    public static class NotesListFragment extends ListFragment {
        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("DEV", "List item clicked.");

            Note note = (Note) l.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteDetail.class);
            String noteTitle = note.getnTitle();
            String noteDescription = note.getnBody();
            int[] entryID = new int[1];
            entryID[0] = note.getNid();

            i.putExtra("newNoteFlag", false);
            i.putExtra("noteTitle", noteTitle);
            i.putExtra("noteBody", noteDescription);
            i.putExtra("entryID", entryID);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }


    private void insertData(String title, String body, String I_URI, String I_Location) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = helpers.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        //content.put(NotesDbAdapter.NOTES_ID,id);
        content.put(NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_TITLE, title);
        content.put(NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_BODY, body);
        // content.put(NotesDbAdapter.NOTES_URI,I_URI);
        //content.put(NotesDbAdapter.NOTES_LOCATION,I_Location);

        database.insert(NoteContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, content);

        // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
        long newRowId;
        newRowId = database.insert(NoteContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, content);

        //database.close();

    }


    class GetNotesFromDbTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(NoteDetail.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Loading");
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


            SQLiteDatabase db = helpers.getReadableDatabase();
            String[] projection = {
                    NoteContract.FeedEntry._ID,
                    NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_TITLE,
                    NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_ID,
                    NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_BODY,

            };
            // How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
            // How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
            String sortOrder =
                    NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_ID + " DESC";

            Cursor cursor = db.query(
                    NoteContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
                    projection,                               // The columns to return
                    null,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
                    null,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
                    null,                                     // don't group the rows
                    null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
                    sortOrder                                 // The sort order

            );


             Log.i("DEV", "Query successful, got the results from DB");
             Log.i("DEV", "Number of rows in DB: " + cursor.getCount());

            if(cursor.getCount()>0)
            {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int entryid = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_ID));
                String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_TITLE));
                String body=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_BODY));
                Note note = new Note(title, body);
                note.setNid(entryid);
                notes.add(note);



            }

       return true;
        }

    }
}
    /*
    private void deleteData(String title, String Title, String I_URI, String I_Locatin)
    {
        NotesDbAdapter dbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(dbHelper.NOTES_TITLE, "New Title");
        database.delete(dbHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, "_ID=?", new String[]{"3"});

    }
*/
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Note> nts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nts= Note.getNotes();

        ArrayAdapter<Note> adp =
                new ArrayAdapter<Note>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,nts);

        NotesListFragment frg = new NotesListFragment();
        frg.setListAdapter(adp);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.linearmy,frg)
                .commit();



    }

    public static class NotesListFragment extends ListFragment{

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    ((Note)getListAdapter().getItem(position)).toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    public void click(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteDetail.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }




    public void clickToAbout(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);



    }

    public void clickToHome(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }



}
```

Comment: Move `insertData(eTitle.getText().toString(), eBody.getText().toString(), URI, Location);` at top before starting new activity.

Comment: I move it, it did not change.